# Why is this CNN showing a loss of nan and accuracy of 0? Full code shown

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a NN which can recognize the letters of the alphabet (26 classes). I apologize for the lengthy post, but I've included all my relevant code to be as clear as possible. In the end I've explained the issue.

The following block is where I name the paths correctly, and standardize/normalize the image and get it ready for training.

```py
X = [] # Image data
y = [] # Labels

#datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True)

# Loops through imagepaths to load images and labels into arrays
for path in imagepaths:
    img = cv2.imread(path) # Reads image and returns np.array
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Converts into the corret colorspace (GRAY) #find rgb 
    img = cv2.resize(img, (75, 75)) # Reduce image size so training can be faster
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    #img = datagen.standardize(img)
    X.append(img)
    # Processing label in image path
    category = path.split("\\")[1]
    #print(category)
    split = (category.split("_"))     
    if int(split[0]) == 0:
        label = int(split[1])
    else:
        label = int(split[0])
    y.append(label)

# Turn X and y into np.array to speed up train_test_split

X = np.array(X, dtype="float") #ORIGINAL uint8
X = X.astype(np.float) / 255.

X = X.reshape(len(imagepaths), 75, 75, 1) # Needed to reshape so CNN knows it's different images, 1 for bw change to 3 for rgb
y = np.array(y)
```

Creating the test set.

```
ts = 0.3 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=ts, random_state=42)
```

Creating a model. Dense of 26, one output for each letter, and size 200,200,1 to match input:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
```

Model compiler and fit:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

The issue comes here where the output of my model.fit is:

```
Train on 54600 samples, validate on 23400 samples
Epoch 1/1
54600/54600 [==============================] - 23s 419us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 1.8315e-05 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

I understand that it may not be high accuracy or anything from the get-go, but why are the losses nan? I posted elsewhere and I was first told to normalize my data (which I fixed for this post). Then I was told that it was possible that my dataset is corrupt or leaking - this is not the case because when I don't do 26 letters at once, it works perfectly fine. (Meaning I tested the code, using letters A-J, dense = 10, etc) and got a high accuracy of about 95%.

Any help is appreciated, I've been scratching my had at this for hours!

Comment: Have you tried `categorical_crossentropy`?

Comment: Simplify the model. What happens when it has just one layer?